# How to fade out a colored box slowly?

Tags: javascript, fade

New to javascript and I got this working, a box turning white, but tried various way to set a fade out time unsuccessfully.

```
document.getElementById("button3").addEventListener("click", function(){           
document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "white";  });
```

Thanks

Comment: If [jquery](https://jquery.com/) is allowed, you just have to `$('#box').animate({backgroundColor:'white'},2000);` ... read [source](https://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use your code and add some css to animate the transitions:

```js
document.getElementById("button3").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "white";
})
```

```css
#box{
  background: gold;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<button id="button3">click</button>
<div id="box">
  test
</div>
```

If you include transition: all 1s; to your class every css change will be animate, you can configure duration change 1s to desired transition duration.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Method**

```
 <style>
  body {
  transition: background-color 2s cubic-bezier(1, 1, 1, 1);
  transition-delay: 0s;
   }
  </style>

<script>
var colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple"];
var currentIndex = 0;

setInterval(function() {
document.body.style.cssText = "background-color: " + colors[currentIndex];
currentIndex++;
if (currentIndex == undefined || currentIndex >= colors.length) {
    currentIndex = 0;
 }
 }, 1000);
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To fade out a colored box slowly follow the below 2 steps:

1. Use **CSS transition property** (allows the changes in CSS property values to occur smoothly over a specified duration).
2. Use JavaScript (***element*.style.display = "none"**) to remove the fadeout element from document flow.

```js
// Get all elements with class="close"
let close = document.querySelectorAll(".close");

for (let i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
    close[i].onclick = function() {
        // Get the parent of <span class="close"> (<div class="alert">)
        let div = this.parentElement;

        // Set the opacity of div to 0
        div.style.opacity = "0";

        // Hide the div after 600ms (the same amount of milliseconds it takes to fade out)
        setTimeout(function() { div.style.display = "none"; }, 600);
    }
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

/* Style Alert Message */
.alert {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1rem 1.9rem 1rem 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  transition: opacity .6s linear;
}

/* Contextual Classes for alert */
.alert-primary {
  color: #004085;
  background-color: #cce5ff;
  border-color: #b8daff;
}

.alert-secondary {
  color: #383d41;
  background-color: #e2e3e5;
  border-color: #d6d8db;
}

.alert-warning {
  color: #856404;
  background-color: #fff3cd;
  border-color: #ffeeba;
}

.alert-danger {
  color: #721c24;
  background-color: #f8d7da;
  border-color: #f5c6cb;
}

/* Style Close Button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: 900;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Click on the &times; icon to fadeout the box:</p>

<div class="alert alert-primary">
  <b>Primary!</b> This alert box indicates an important action.
  <button type="button" class="close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>

<div class="alert alert-warning">
  <b>Warning!</b> This alert box could indicate a warning that might need attention.
  <button type="button" class="close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>

<div class="alert alert-danger">
  <b>Danger!</b> This alert box could indicate a dangerous or potentially negative action.
  <button type="button" class="close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>

<div class="alert alert-secondary">
  <b>Secondary!</b> This alert box indicates a less important action.
  <button type="button" class="close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
```